# Trying to simplify this JavaScript expression dealing with undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to preserve the `undefined` if pinned is actually undefined, otherwise, I want to set the value across the equals sign to 1 if pinned is true and 0 if it's false.  I came up with this that works, but I keep looking at it and it seems like it should be simpler.

`const resultingValue = pinned === undefined ? undefined : pinned ? 1 : 0;`

What I'm wanting is:

if pinned is undefined, return undefined
if pinned is true, return 1
if pinned is false, return 0
otherwise, return 0;

Comment: `typeof pinned === 'boolean' ? pinned : undefined`

Comment: You already have equivalent answers, but I recommend `pinned === undefined ? undefined : Number(pinned)` for readability.

Comment: THanks @Ry-, I like your answer the best so far.

Answer (score 3):

You could check type and return either a number of boolean or `undefined`.

```
const
    resultingValue = typeof pinned === 'boolean'
        ? +pinned
        : undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for: `true`, `false`, `undefined`, `0`, `1`

```
const resultingValue = +pinned + 1 ? +pinned: undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup table for each value. The `undefined` can be omitted since it is going to produce `undefined` by default:

```js
const lookup = {true: 1, false: 0};
const convert = value => 
  lookup[value];

console.log(convert(true));
console.log(convert(false));
console.log(convert(undefined));
console.log(convert());
```

This can be shortened to a single function, if desired:

```js
const convert = value => 
  ({true: 1, false: 0}[value]);

console.log(convert(true));
console.log(convert(false));
console.log(convert(undefined));
console.log(convert());
```